# Make Entire Area of New Graphic Editable

Tags: graphics

Create a new graphic via the menu bar: `Graphics -> New Graphic`.

The `FullForm` expression for this graphic is:

```
Graphics[{}, ContentSelectable -> True, ImageSize -> {480, 360}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4/3}, {0, 1}}]
```

Using the Drawing Tools palette, the entire area of the newly created graphic is editable:

[image: fullyeditable]

Suppose now I want to make a new graphic but make it taller; that is, I want a new graphic but with dimension 480 x 800. I can do so with `Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {480, 800}]` but only a small part of it is editable.

[image: noteditable]

If I add a `PlotRange`, for example, `Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {480, 800}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 4/3}}]`, the editable area increases.

[image: noteditable2]

To make the entire area editable, I can change `PlotRange` to `{{0, 1}, {0, 5/3}}`.

[image: noteidtable3]

If I change `ImageSize`, is there a systematic way to choose `PlotRange` to make the entire area editable? Other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: Does `PlotRange -> All` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `AspectRatio -> Full` fixes this behavior:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {480, 800}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

`Graphics` has `AspectRatio -> Automatic` by default and this results in addition of non-zero `ImagePadding` inside of `ImageSize` but outside of `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` and because of the latter `PlotRangeClipping -> False` alone does not fix this behavior completely. `PlotRange -> All` is expected to fix this but it does not.

Instead of `AspectRatio -> Full` one can specify explicit `AspectRatio` based on `ImageSize` with the same effect:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {400, 800}, AspectRatio -> 800/400]
```

Another approach would be to tune `PlotRange` for `ImageSize` with `AspectRatio -> Automatic`. Now the `PlotRange` occupies all the `ImageSize` and the area of the graphic and it is completely editable:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {400, 800}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}]
```

Another approach is to tune up both `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding` to occupy the complete `ImageSize`:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {400, 800}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {0, {.5, .5}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```